# Go - AppEngine - Performance

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I have Go app that receives JSON in POST and stores it in a Datastore (AppEngine)

The statistic for first 24 hours:

40 entities were stored in datastore. (every entity is small less 1K, JSON with 7-10 fields)
**7.20** Instance hours consumed.

7 hours is much more then I expected. I expected to see 7 seconds or even 1 second.

Is that normal?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instance hours means how long your app standup. As GAE will go idle if no request in 15 minutes, in your case, if there is a request every 15 minutes, you may max cost `40req*15min/60=10hour` instance hours. So `7.2` instance hours is possible.

Comment: Yes, an idle instance is still charged until it is shut down. If you have a very low request rate but still at least one every 15m then your instance will remain alive.